# Sending email by servlets

Tags: java, servlets

```
Properties props = new Properties();

props.setProperty("mail.smtps.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable","true");
props.setProperty("mail.debug", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtps.auth", "true");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class","javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");

Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(login, password);

Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
session.setDebug(true);
try
{     
    MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
    msg.setText(message);
    msg.setSubject(subject);
    msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
    msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

    Transport.send(msg);
}
```

I am trying to send an email through servlet.But I am getting MessagingException in this code.And most probably,this exception is thrown by Transport.send(msg).How can I get out of this?

Comment: Have u include API for the same???

Comment: If I am not wrong then properties should be System.getprpoerties();

Answer (score 0):

Well if u not mind using java mail then u can use this. Try this..

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm